# Jira vs AzureDevOps Board

Tags: azure-devops, jira

**Edit**

After discussing with Jira Support & lots of tech teams using it, here are a few tricks:

- A large amount of Plugins slows down Jira - ex: InVision plugin
- Same for "Custom fields": remove all the unnecessary ones
- Minimize the amount of info within a card and keep Jira for delivery management only => we had too much info within the description of the cards (including tech specs) and that had a major impact on speed
- There are known bugs regarding card editing, descriptions should be kept short

---

**The issue**

We encounter a lot of problems with Jira. The main ones being:
- Very slow
- Bugs when we edit a card: lost content
- Hard to configure

**Context**

We are a team of ~20 (15 devs + 5 product).
We use the SCRUM methodology, but currently moving to KANBAN (similar though).

**Questions**

Some would like to use Azure DevOps instead of Jira.
I have serious doubts about the fact that it would be a good move. So here are my questions:

1. Do you encounter the problems mentioned above?
2. What do you think of Azure DevOps Board compared to Jira?
3. Is there any problem with Azure DevOps (vs Jira) that we should be aware of?

Thanks a lot!

*ps: I could not find any recent discussion on this topic*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you encounter the problems mentioned above?

Just personal experience, I haven't met such scenario so far: Lost content when editing card.

> What do you think of Azure DevOps Board compared to Jira?

Hmm, I'm not familiar with Jira. I just find one document which may help: [Azure Boards vs Jira Software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/compare/azure-boards-vs-jira)

> Is there any problem with Azure DevOps that we should be aware of?

This question is too board... Check the related [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/what-is-azure-boards?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Lance for your time and answers.
FYI, I edited the card with the info I could glance on this topic.